# ag-Grid not rendering correctly in Vue (in combination with Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, vuetify.js

I'm trying to set up a project using Vue, and am having problems making it render correctly. The grid does render initially, but when you scroll horizontally, the grid seems broken. It's not rendering the columns and rows outside it's initial viewport.

You can see the rendering problem occur in the following sandbox, by scrolling horizontally in the grid (mac users: click on a cell and navigate using the arrows):
https://codesandbox.io/s/jn0o4q630w.